# Reversing tuples inside a list with fold_left in Ocaml

Tags: list, tuples, ocaml, reverse, fold

Let `lst` be a List with tuples which I want to reverse each (The order of the tuples needs to be the same). For example:

```
[(a,b);(c,d)] -> [(b,a);(d,c)]
```

I know that it can be done with map:

```
List.map (fun (a,b) -> (b,a)) [(1,2);(3,4)];;
- : (int * int) list = [(2, 1); (4, 3)]
```

But I´m looking for a way to achieve it with `List.fold_left`. My approach is to match the list with `[]` as a accumulator to concatenate every reversed tuple together, but I keep getting type-Errors:

```
List.fold_left (fun (a,b) -> (b,a)) [] lst;;
```

Comment: `List.map` is such a natural fit for this problem, I'm not sure why you'd want to use `List.fold_left`.

Answer (score 0):

`List.fold_left` takes three arguments:

- A function of type `'a -> 'b -> 'a`
- An accumulator of type `'a`
- A list of type `'b list`

Your function `(fun (a,b) -> (b,a))` is missing an argument, the accumulator, on which you want to concatenate the reversed pairs

```ml
(fun acc (a,b) -> (b,a) :: acc)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `List.map` seems like a natural option here, because you could do something like:

`List.map (fun (a, b) -> (b, a)) lst`

But if you wanted to use `List.fold_left` then you need to reverse each pair and then cons it to the accumulator list:

`List.fold_left (fun acc (a, b) -> (b, a)::acc) [] lst`

Since fold_left takes the following function signature: `('a -> 'b -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'b list -> 'a`, you need to make sure that your first argument is a function that takes in an accumulator list and an individual list element (in this case a tuple), and then returns a list.

EDIT: @Chris rightly pointed out that with this solution the order of the tuples themselves would also flip. You can fix this by wrapping the function with `List.rev`, or instead of cons-ing you can append the tuple to the end of the list:

`List.fold_left (fun acc (a, b) -> acc@[(b, a)]) [] lst`

Answer (score 0):

Both the answer by @Lhooq and @rithvik are mostly spot-on, but will reverse the order of the tuples in the resulting list.

We either need to feed the result to `List.rev` *or* use `List.fold_right`.

```
utop # List.fold_left (fun acc (a, b) -> (b, a) :: acc) [] [(1, 2); (3, 4)] |> List.rev;;
- : (int * int) list = [(2, 1); (4, 3)]
```

```
utop # List.fold_right (fun (a, b) acc -> (b, a) :: acc) [(1, 2); (3, 4)] [];;
- : (int * int) list = [(2, 1); (4, 3)]
```